# How do i make a background image right click able?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I gave up on trying to center an image vertically and horizontally. I seen solutions that require you to know the size of the image. I do know background-image will center it properly. However i cannot right click the image and hit save as. Is there a trick i can use to allow this?

Comment: You may want to ask this question over at http://doctype.com

Comment: @Thomas: If you can give me an example and say use an image. I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @Thomas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478434/center-an-image-vertically-and-horizontally-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this potential answer?

http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

His solution is pure HTML+CSS, doesn't require foreknowledge of the image height and works in: Opera 6+. Safari, IE5+/Win, and IE5/Mac.

Answer (score 4):

You can always add an `<img>` in the `<div>` that you are setting the background for. And set the opacity to 0.

Users can't see it but they can still right click and save it.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.
Background images are not intended to be any more than a pretty surrounding for the important parts and there is no reason why they should be easily downloadable.

Answer (score 1):

In firefox you can view background images. Then you can save the image

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug plugin](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox. You can browse to the DOM element and then find the background image. Then there's an option to "open image in tab". From there saving it is simple.

I assume this is for development purposes and not something you want end users to do.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your browser -- in Firefox3, you may use Tools->Page Info->Media, locate the image from the list and hit "Save As..."

I think an HTML/CSS option is not possible, but I'm not completely sure.