# Vertically centering image in a div tag

Tags: css, image, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Center an Image vertically and horizontally? css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478434/center-an-image-vertically-and-horizontally-css)

How would I go about setting an image I have in a div tag to be in the exact centre?

I can only find guides for `text-align:center;`, and that places it in the middle but doesn't adjust the vertical height.

Comment: Just search on SO, this question is asked a lot.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478434/center-an-image-vertically-and-horizontally-css

Answer (score 3):

There are two options for dynamic vertical centering.

1. You use Javascript to get the height of the element and then do some math to set the top of the element to half of the height of the parent minus half of the element.
2. You use `display: table` and percentages to get it to align properly, as shown by [this article](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).

I've also had some luck with `line-height` and `vertical-align`, but that's not dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Position centering has long been an issue with css. All of the above suggestions work, but every one of them has a slightly hacky feel. If you don't need to support IE or Opera, start using the html5 flexible-box model which is awesome: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

```
.centerbox {
  /* basic styling */
  width: 350px;
  height: 95px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  background : #CFC;

  /* flexbox, por favor */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;

  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;

  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  box-pack: center;
  box-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the height of your image, position it absolutely with `top: 50%` and a top margin that is half the height of the image.  So for a 100x100 image:

```
div.imgContainer
{
    position: relative;
}
div.imgContainer > img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick doing it with line-height:

```
<div style="
height: /*div height in px here */ px; 
line-height: /*div height in px here */ px;
text-align:center;">

<img src="URL" style="vertical-align:middle;" />

</div>
```