# Vertically Centering image in fixed container

Tags: html, css

I am using wordpress to dynamically display images. Each image has a fixed width of 186 px and variable height, depending on the proportions of the image. Each image sits in a square box, with 15px padding. By default, the images appear at the top of the box. I am looking for a way to vertically center the image, given its fixed width, but variable height. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="logoContainer">
    <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logoContainer {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #dddddc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 186px;
    height: 186px;
}
.logoContainer img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I could use absolute positioning, but without knowing the exact height of the image, it would be difficult to perfectly center. BUT, we do know the exact dimensions of the container box. Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center an Image vertically and horizontally using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478434/center-an-image-vertically-and-horizontally-using-css)

Comment: Is the maximum possible image height 156px? That's what your CSS implies, or would you like to account for any possible height?

Comment: that question is more related to a jQuery alternative to css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/vLbRF/

```
.logoContainer {
    padding:15px;
    background:#dddddc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width:186px;
    height:186px;
    line-height: 186px;
}

.logoContainer img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this technique which implements `vertical-align` will allow you to have dynamic-height containers:

```
<div class="logoContainer">
    <span></span><img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logoContainer {
    padding:15px; 
    background:#dddddc; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    width:186px; 
    height:186px; }
span {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
.logoContainer img { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
```