# Vertically center image with 100% width in li with fixed dimensions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center an image placed in a fixed width and height li.
My basic HTML is:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my basic CSS is:

```
.list-item {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #63A578;
}

.list-item div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.list-item img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've tried variations of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267158/vertically-centering-image-in-fixed-container) answer (and a lot of others) which works until the container becomes smaller than the image height. It then stops being vertically aligned and overflows it's container ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8zd7cyt/17/) here).

So basically I'm looking to vertically align a 100% width img in a fixed height container that is smaller than the image height without it overflowing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table-cell` to the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/d8zd7cyt/18/

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/d8zd7cyt/21/

Comment: If you switch the image dimensions from 400x200 to 200x400 (ie the height is larger than the width) it still overflows.
Is there a general solution?

Comment: I've made a few changes to the CSS to simplify a little and hopefully achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Although the update does fix the overflow problem it doesn't vertically center the image in the li, it displays it normally starting from the top left corner.