# Centering image in div vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to center an image, can be of various sizes, in a div both vertically and horizontally. All of the images are made to fit in the div, however, they vary in size.

How would I do it?

CSS:

```
.item-image-box {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #382418;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the height of the div?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2478434/1004046)

Comment: Just went through all of those answers, none worked.

Comment: Adding a live demo (using a site like jsfiddle.net) would be helpful. Does the image tag itself have any CSS applied, like `position:absolute` for instance? (seeing as the container has `position:relative`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the powers of background positioning and inline styles.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F6PBJ/

### HTML

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/90/40)"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/40/40)"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/40/90)"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/60/80)"></div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #382418;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-right: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `div`:

```
text-align: center;
line-height: /*height of your div*/
```

For the `img`:

```
margin: auto;
```

Comment: It only horizontally centered it. :/

Comment: @ShadyPotato Make the div's line-height the same as its height.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized, `vertical-alignment` worked only in the days of table-layouts.

Answer (score 0):

background

```
div {
       background: url(/path/to/img.png) no-repeat center center;
    }
```

display:table-cell and vertical-align: middle method

You could also use vertical-align: middle.

```
div {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Vt5ed/

Taken from CSS Tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/hJtpF/

Comment: The image will vary depending on the value I put into it (i.e. from a database)

Comment: For a foreground image, the `position:absolute` approach only works if the size of the image is known, which it isn't.

Comment: The absolute position method also didn't work. Had to fiddle with the margins and then when I changed the image to a larger one, it wasn't centered.

Comment: fairly certain you want this than:   http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/hJtpF/

Comment: Still not working. :/

Comment: What is the HTML context that you are working in?  Several posted solutions seem to  be able to work in the various fiddles.  Everyone seems to be working in the dark, please shed some light.